How to auto reconnect bluetooth peripheral when restart bluetooth?

I have connected to the Bluetooth peripheral.
Turn off Bluetooth from Control Center.
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(nullable NSError *)error; is called.
In the callback method, I will get the central.state. If it is .poweredOn, I will automatically reconnect.

But when i turn off Bluetooth from Control Center. The central.state I got is .poweredOn in the method - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(nullable NSError *)error; (In fact, it should be .poweredOff, but the central.state has not been updated yet.)
If I reconnect the peripheral at this time, I will definitely fail.
Originally, I planned to reconnect automatically if central.state was .poweredOn on here. But at present, due to the reasons described above, it is not very feasible.
How should I correctly develop this automatic reconnection process?

When you get a didDisconnect callback issue a connect.  That is all you need to do.  You can track the Bluetooth power state to show a warning to the user, but you don't need to track it in order to reconnect.

You can use the centralManagerDidUpdateState(_:) method to observe powerdOff state
